# Sitecore switches user session with another user

Tags: session, asp.net-membership, sitecore, session-state, sitecore6

I have an FBA site that uses Sitecore.  Every so often, it will confuse one user with another.  What I mean is, somehow User A will unintentionally hijack User B's session.  User A will be looking at a page that a) they don't have permission to view, and that's b) customized for User B.  The one time I was able to reproduce (accidentally) , I got my original session back after I clicked through to another page.

I know Sitecore leverages the Aspnet membership DB, so this might be an issue with that DB, but I really couldn't guess.  It feels more like a session issue than anything else.  Also, this is not happening on a cluster, but on a standalone machine.

Anyway, any information - even theories - could help.  I don't think I've ever seen anything quite like this before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar issue long ago. It turned out that there was a static (shared) method retrieving the user (or session). That was not a Sitecore bug but rather a bad implementation... Not at all sure this is your problem but it might be worth to check that no fields or methods used to access the user are shared.

Comment: This was exactly it.  There was a static class returning a User item from one of it's members.  The insidious thing was, though, that there was an initialization function being used as a kind of constructor,  so it would work most of the time.  The only time you'd have problems was when this happened:

1) User A calls the initialize function
2) User B calls the initialize function
3) User A reads a property from the class

So now User A is reading a property that User B initialized.


Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a similar issue described below

1. You view the site as a logged in Extranet User - Sitecore happily
   does this for you
2. You open a new tab in the browser and log into the Sitecore backend
3. Sitecore switches you to be your Sitecore user
4. You click back and navigate around the site - Sitecore now uses the Sitecore user to
   navigate around the frontend of the site

So could it be that you (or someone has logged as separate extranet users in different tabs?)

Comment: Actually, the users are on entirely different machines.  Thanks.  :-)