# How to Structure VB.NET Class Securely and Correctly

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session

I am having a really tough time with structuring a Class that is used throughout the application.
The problem is the exact same issue as described here:
[Sitecore switches user session with another user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11660964/sitecore-switches-user-session-with-another-user)

A session variable is being shared by any secondary user that logs in AFTER the first user.
My Class basically assigns a permission level to the session object, so that each page and or control can read it without doing a trip to the DB.

The Class Structure is as follows:

```
Public NotInheritable Class cPermissions
    Public Shared Sub AssignPermissionToSession(ByVal UserID As Integer)
    Private Shared Sub SetInSession(key As String, value As Dictionary(Of String, String))
    Public Shared Function HasPerm(ByVal ControlName As String) as Boolean
End Class
```

So to explain the process: User Logs in. The login code calls cPermissions.AssignPermissionToSession(UserID). That Sub calls SetInSession which assigns the permission dictionary to a session object.

As a sidenote, I would prefer a NotInheritable class in this instance as it allows me to shorthand through the code, using the Shared Function HasPerm without instantiating the class. HasPerm reads the session object and returns true or false if the control has permission or not.

So back to the original problem, according to the previous link mentioned at the start, because the Sub is shared, I am experiencing session Hijacking.
But if I don't share the SetInSession sub, the shared sub AssignPermissionsToSession (which login needs to see) cant access it.

So basically I would really appreciate if someone could instruct me how to structure this class correctly without experiencing Accidental Session Hijacking.
Thanks in Advance!

The Code as requested is as follows (shrunk for brevity):

```
Public NotInheritable Class cPermissions
    'local dictionary that gets created, and then assigned to session
    Private Shared dPermissions As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    Public Shared Sub AssignPermissionToSession(ByVal UserID As Integer)
        dPermissions.Clear() 
        'Here I open DB and get a list of Roles that each member may have
        While ....
            BuildPermissionArray()
        End While

        'Now dPermission should be created assign to session
        SetInSession("Permissions", dPermissions)
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub BuildPermissionArray()
         'Here we create the local Dictionary ready for the session
         'So for each role we get each permission for each control ie:
         dPermissions.add(control,perm)
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub SetInSession(ByVal key As String, value As Dictionary(Of String, String))
        If value Is Nothing Then
            HttpContext.Current.Session(key) = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
        Else
            HttpContext.Current.Session(key) = value
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function HasPermission(ByVal PermissionType As Permission, ByVal ControlName As String) As Boolean
        Dim obj As Object = HttpContext.Current.Session("Permissions")
        Dim d As Dictionary(Of String, String) = DirectCast(obj, Dictionary(Of String, String))
        'Here I search the dictionary and check relevant permission for the control name
        Return result
    End Function
End Class
```

Now the Login code calls:
    cPermissions.AssignPermissionToSession(UserID)

And each page load reads the controls on the current page and calls:
    cPermissions.HasPermission(View,"PageOrControlName")

Comment: I don't believe you've provided enough implementation detail for a diagnosis. You've got the method signatures, but the fault surely lies in the implementation of those methods? Maybe you're getting the session object and static variables mixed up?

Comment: Hi Snixtor, I can assure you that im only assigning and reading from a session variable. I excluded code because the first link I posted explains that its because in using a Shared Sub/Method to access or assign the Session Var - but I just have no idea how to do it without sharing it...

Comment: "A session variable is being shared by any secondary user..." - would an [Application State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594.ASPX) variable be a better choice, seeing as a Session variable is specific to the Session?

Comment: Hi Andrew - I DONT want the variable to be shared! But somehow because of my implementation, the session variable is being shared by users! So the second user that logs in, his permission session var overwrites the first users session var...

Comment: I see that you are using `Shared Sub`. Do you have any `Shared` data? That would be shared between users.

Comment: Hi John, no only the functionality is shared, not the data. But if I make the SetinSession Sub not shared - I cant call it from AssignPermissionToSession sub...

Comment: And I can assure you the fault lies in the implementation. Without providing detail of your implementation, you are forcing everyone to guess, which won't get you a quick answer, if any answer at all.

Comment: Show us the code where this is setting permissions in session, or reading from session.  We had an issue once where the user was being read once in a filter and stored, but filters are shared (thus are users were given the same permissions as the first user who logged in).  Showing us the code is best.

Comment: Hi readers - I have added code to the question. Thanks for reading and assisting - I excluded most logic that wasn't related to setting and getting the session var. Hope its enough for you to go on...

Comment: `dPermissions` is a shared variable at the class level, concurrent uses of the `cPermissions` class will be using the same variable simultaneously.

Comment: Hi Snixtor - I wondered about that but now how would I share a variable between subs and functions, without sharing it between users? Thanks for your help - really is appreciated

Comment: However now that I think about it, how does the second user that logs in OVERWRITES the Session Var of the first user? And im talking about a login that takes place 5 mins after the first user logs in!